# change $_POST to seperate function parameters in PHP

Tags: php, ajax, parsing, variables, post

The problem is easy to explain. What I want to do is to create an object, parameters and function calls based on $_POST variables.

```
$obj = new $_POST['object']['name']($_POST['object']['params']);

            return json_encode(
                 $obj->$_POST['function']['name']($_POST['function']['params'])
            );
```

The only problem here is that it gives the parameters as an array. And I want it to seperate the variables with a comma, like: `$obj->function($var1 , $var2, $var3);`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: First of all its not good using Post data as variable names before you filter/check

Comment: Also: this is basically a very minimal router. Maybe you should use an existing framework if you need things like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to create object without arguments passed to constructor and initiate it using some other method. For example:

```
$obj = new $_POST['object']['name']();
$result = call_user_func_array(array($obj,'init'),$_POST['object']['params']);
```

Also, in PHP 5.4+ you can use this "hack":

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass($_POST['object']['name']);
$obj = $reflection->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();
call_user_func_array(array($obj,'__constructor'),$_POST['object']['params']);
```

But I advise you to change your architecture so you would be able to pass array to constructor "as is".

Comment: Guess I'm going for a func_get_args function in a superclass that checks if the first parameter is an array or not. So I'll be taking your advice :)

Answer (score 3):

This can be done, but you should only do it using a white list of possible objects to create. Otherwise it is kind of dangerous.  A system this open may not be a good idea. If you can rethink the problem it may help to approach it a different way.

To solve your problem though, you can use a construct like this:

```
// Possible values:
$acceptable_classes = array('myClass1', 'myClass2', 'myClass3');

// If it is an allowed class,
if (in_array($_POST['object']['name'], $acceptable_classes) {
  // Store it in a variable.
  $class = $_POST['object']['name'];

  $obj = new $class;
}
```

You need to keep a similar whitelist for the function. You might use a multidimensional array for that.  You may extend this to hold acceptable parameters for the possible functions. It can blow out of proportion pretty quickly, but will help maintain security.

```
$acceptable_classes = array(
  'myClass1' => array(
    'func1', 'func2'
  ),
  'myClass2' => array(
    'func3', 'func4'
  )
);

if ($acceptable_classes, array_key_exists($_POST['object']['name']) {
  if (in_array($_POST['function']['name'], $acceptable_classes($_POST['object']['name'])) {
    // Store it in a variable.
    $class = $_POST['object']['name'];

    $obj = new $class;
    $func = $_POST['function']['name'];
    return json_encode($obj->$func($_POST['function']['params']));
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you place the variables? Will use the whitelist anyway :) that's a great idea

Comment: @Zundrium See additions above for whitelisting the function too.

Comment: instead of showing me how to maintain security this still doesn't show me how to solve the parameter array problem, which is call_user_func_array() :/ Still need to find out how to do the same with classes though

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this:

```
call_user_func_array( array($obj, $_POST['function']['name']), $_POST['function']['params'])
```

[Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) of the `call_user_func_array` function

Comment: Well, this eliminates 1 part, but what about calling an object with parameters the same way?

Comment: What do you mean by "calling an object"? If it's constructing a new instance, then the accepted answer is exactly what I'd do.

Answer (score 2):

[call_user_func_array()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) is what you're looking for. On a side note, running $_POST values is a security risk, I hope you sanitize them properly.

Comment: Well, this eliminates 1 part, but what about calling an object with parameters the same way? ( same as above )

Answer (score 0):

have the function take an array

```
$name = $_POST['object']['name'];

$obj = new $name;

$array = explode(',', $_POST['object']['params'];
$obj->function($array);
```